# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version,Fix plugin version and sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins

I have setup android studio 2.2 and my sdk contains api 23 as well as api 24.
My build.gradle file is as below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sanjay.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
}
```

I have getting below error :

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "9d813ee66dd60f65615706c5deaa14afed669ca5"
```

`Fix plugin version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:\MyApplication2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>`

Please let me know, Whats going wrong here, Thank you.

Comment: Have you updated your gradle version?

Answer (score 0):

When such error is shown (**Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, Fix plugin version, and sync project**), click on the **Fix plugin version and sync project** which appeared in the log cat. the Gradle will sync and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Project level `Build.gradle` to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest gradle from https://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and
Goto: Build, Execution, Deployment ->> Build Tools ->> Gradle (Or just type in the searchbar Gradle) 
Select: (X) Use local gradle distribution and set Gradle home to your extracted Gradle directory. Click on apply.

Update your Project  Build.gradle to

```
dependencies 
{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle: "latest version here"  '
}
```

see [Grade Version Compatibility for Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw819.png)